# Error while gathering tablenames from Database c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

Database Name is ONLINEEXAM

I have several tables in the db and I want to list some table names starts with letters "set % " in Dropdownlist in asp.net.

I use the following code and I'm getting the error :  **invalid object name ONLINEEXAM.dbo.sysobjects**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        paperset();
    }  
}


private void paperset()
{
    try
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "select * from ONLINEEXAM.dbo.sysobjects where name like 'Set%'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Value = dr[0].ToString();
            papersetlist.Items.Add(item);
        }

        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    }
    finally { }
}
```

Comment: try to run the query w/o db name like this select * from sysobjects where name like 'Set%'

Comment: what is your connectionstring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are running query against a different database, run you query in sql server to check it.
also try this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from sys.objects where name like 'Set%'", con);
```

or use this to get all the tables

```
select * from sys.tables where name like 'Set%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to verify the user ID has access to the `sysobjects` table. 
Assuming you are running SQL2005 or later, you can also look at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema and review the `TABLES` view:

```
Select TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE 
from [database.]INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```